# Cassandra 1.2 migration : Broken pipe

Tags: cassandra

We migrated our cluster to Cassandra 1.2 (from 1.1.7) and we tried to run a repair after the migration (we run them periodically, as recommended).

The repair failed due to the SSTable version being different, so we used `nodetool upgradesstables` and `nodetool scrub` and retried.

But then the repair failed with this exception :

```
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at com.google.common.base.Throwables.propagate(Throwables.java:160)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.transferTo0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.transferToDirectly(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.transferTo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.compress.CompressedFileStreamTask.stream(CompressedFileStreamTask.java:90)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.FileStreamTask.runMayThrow(FileStreamTask.java:91)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28)
```

We also noticed that before dying, `nodetool netstats` shows weird statistics (SSTable transfers being at 756845%...).

**EDIT**

It seems to be a problem with the transfer of compressend SSTables, I will try to disable compression on this ColumnFamily and retry.

**RE-EDIT**

Disabling compression fixed the problem so we tried to re-enable it and got a

```
java.lang.RuntimeException:
  Last written key DecoratedKey(97115[...]3136) >= current key DecoratedKey(8...
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was caused by a bug in Cassandra 1.2, affecting transfers of compressed column families between nodes. It was fixed in 1.2.2 => [Jira entry for this bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-5105).